# How to avoid repeating large amounts of code and apply the same rule to multiple classes

Tags: jquery

I have 12 images for example and on image click I want to hide the 11 other images and increase the clicked upon image to full screen

I'm trying to work out if there is an easier more straight forward way to make this happen rather than writing a huge amount of code along the lines of

```
$('.image_one').click(function() {
    $('.image_one').addClass('increase_size');
    $('.image_two').hide(); ...etc for the other 11 images
});
```

x 12 for all images

My knowledge of jQuery and Javascript are reasonably beginner so I was hoping someone might be able to suggest something to simplify this for what I'm trying to achieve

Not asking for someone to write out this code for me just point me in the general direction

Comment: *"...I want to hide the 11 other images and increase the clicked upon image to full screen"* If any of the 12 images goes to full screen there's no need to hide anything let alone the 11 remaining images. Any element set to full screen will fill the screen in its entirety, ergo there's nothing else to hide because everything is hidden behind the element in full screen mode. Review my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59814987/2813224) for a solution that allows you to control 1 to a bazillion (theoretically if such technology existed) images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the code below. Basically, when the user clicks on an image, all the images will be hidden. Then the image that was clicked on will be showed and that class will be added to it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // User clicks on one of the images
  $(".image").click(function() {
    // Hide all the images
    $(".image").hide();

    // Show the image that the user clicks on
    $(this).show();

    // Add the class to the image the user clicks on
    $(this).addClass("increase_size");
  });

});
```

```css
.increase_size{
    /* your styles */
}

/* Styles to make the image look like box, you won't need this */

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}


/* note, the id's are just to add backgorund to each color, don't need this either. */

#image1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#image2 {
  background-color: green;
}

#image3 {
  background-color: black;
}

#image4 {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test Webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="image1.jpg" class="image" id="image1">
  <img src="image2.jpg" class="image" id="image2">
  <img src="image3.jpg" class="image" id="image3">
  <img src="image4.jpg" class="image" id="image4">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You see... Simple. Hope this helps. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it with 2 steps:

1. Remove all increase_sizeClass
2. Add all increase_sizeClass except the clicked element

```js
var imageClass = ".image";
var increase_sizeClass = "increase_size";

$(imageClass).on("click", function(){
   // Step 1: Remove all increase_sizeClass
   $(imageClass).removeClass(increase_sizeClass);

   // Step 2: Add all increase_sizeClass except the clicked element
   $(imageClass).not(this).each(function(){
         $(this).addClass(increase_sizeClass);
     });
});
```

```css
.image{
width: 50px; 
height: 50px;
float:left ;
background-color:red;
}

.image.increase_size{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 0.8;
    /*You can css here as you wish*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image">Image1</div>
<div class="image">Image2</div>
<div class="image">Image3</div>
<div class="image">Image4</div>
<div class="image">Image5</div>
<div class="image">Image6</div>
<div class="image">Image7</div>
<div class="image">Image8</div>
<div class="image">Image9</div>
<div class="image">Image10</div>
<div class="image">Image11</div>
<div class="image">Image12</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @glittergirl

Answer (score 2):

Basically the following procedures must be implemented somehow:

- Find a common ancestor of all `<img>` and then delegate an event to it.

  ```
  $('.list').on("click",...
  ```
- Designate `this` (aka `event.target`) as the element that the user clicked or hovered over, etc and assign the event handler (aka callback function)

  ```
  $('.list').on("click", 'img', zoomIt)
  ```
- The callback function should be able to process the Event Object so that `this` will always be the clicked element. In doing so, the clicked element's "state" can be changed and the rest of the elements may be safely excluded.

  ```
  $('.list img').not(this).removeClass('on');
  $(this).toggleClass('on');
  ```

By delegating events to the ancestor element, you never need to worry about the amount of elements you have currently or even in the future (should any new target elements be added dynamically after page load). The clicked element is your only concern (aka `event.target`, aka `this`).

---

#### Demo

Further details are commented in demo

**NOTE:** The following Snippet does not function due to SO security measures. For a functioning demo, review this [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/g093b7dw/)

```js
/*
Delegate the "click" event to <ul> with .on() jQuery method

The first parameter ['click'] -- is the event 
(aka event.type) which the ancestor element 
(aka event.currentTarget) listens for

The second parameter ['img'] -- (aka event.data) determines "this" , basically the element the user clicked
(aka event.target)

The third parameter [zoomIt] -- (aka Event Handler or callback) will be invoked when the event is triggered
*/
$(function() {
  $('.list').on('click', 'img', zoomIt);
});

/*
Find all <img> within <ul> and remove the .on class with the exception of the clicked <img>

If the clicked <img> doesn't have class .on then add it, otherwise remove it

Finally if the clicked <img> ends up with .on class -- fullscreen it. 
Otherwise remove fullscreen
*/
function zoomIt(event) {
  $('.list img').not(this).removeClass('on');
  $(this).toggleClass('on');

  if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
    if (this.requestFullscreen) {
      this.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (this.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      this.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (this.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      this.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (clicked.msRequestFullscreen) {
      this.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen()
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 3vw/1.5 Verdana;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

main {
  width: 90vw;
  height: auto;
  margin: 15vh auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 30vw;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li img {
  width: 30vw;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <ul class='list'>
    <li><img src='https://i.ibb.co/hZj77BZ/lena01.jpg'></li>
    <li><img src='https://i.ibb.co/7XxsBr5/lena02.png'></li>
    <li><img src='https://i.ibb.co/X7SCb3w/lena03.png'></li>
    <li><img src='https://i.ibb.co/hZj77BZ/lena01.jpg'></li>
    <li><img src='https://i.ibb.co/7XxsBr5/lena02.png'></li>
    <li><img src='https://i.ibb.co/X7SCb3w/lena03.png'></li>
    <li><img src='https://i.ibb.co/hZj77BZ/lena01.jpg'></li>
    <li><img src='https://i.ibb.co/7XxsBr5/lena02.png'></li>
    <li><img src='https://i.ibb.co/X7SCb3w/lena03.png'></li>
    <li><img src='https://i.ibb.co/hZj77BZ/lena01.jpg'></li>
    <li><img src='https://i.ibb.co/7XxsBr5/lena02.png'></li>
    <li><img src='https://i.ibb.co/X7SCb3w/lena03.png'></li>
  </ul>
</main>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you could try: `$("img:not(.image-one)").hide();`

EDIT: It was pointed out that I should explain this for future reference, so here goes.

jQuery allows you to use most CSS selectors to select elements, therefore we can use the `:not()` pseudo-selector to make it so that certain elements are not affected by what is being changed.

In this example, we see that all the images on the page are selected, then we are specifying `.image-one` inside the `:not()` selector omit it from the list of elements that are going to be hidden.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation or details to your answer. While it might answer the question, just adding a piece of code as an answer, doesn't per say help OP or future community members understand the issue or the proposed solution.